# How to display Custom Page Inside Web Part Page

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part, page-viewer-web-part

In one part of my portal I have a Web-Part page, and I want to use one of the zones to display a Custom Page (just a wiki page from a Team Site in the `Site Page` library) inside that zone.

If I use a Content-Editor, it displays code gibberish.

If I use a Page-Viewer, it shows the Custom Page with the portal header and everything.

How can I show just the custom page portion inside my Web-Part zone?

[I know I could upload custom html to a document libary and then display *that* in a content-editor, but then you lose the WYSIWYG RichText editor functionality]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were trying to display a web part page, you could accomplish this using a page viewer web part, as detailed in my original answer below. However, wiki pages will throw an error if they cannot find the ribbon.

**Embed a web part page (not a wiki page) using a Page Viewer Web Part**

When specifying the URL of the page that the page viewer web part should display, add "**?isDlg=1**" to the end of the URL. This causes SharePoint to treat the page as if it were in a dialog box, so it will strip out the quick launch and top navigation bars.

So for example, if the URL of your page is `http://mysite/mysubsite/mylibrary/mypage.aspx` you'd want to enter `http://mysite/mysubsite/mylibrary/mypage.aspx?isDlg=1` into the page viewer web part's URL property.

**Embedding a wiki page using a Page Viewer Web Part**

As mentioned earlier, wiki pages don't play nicely with `isDlg=1`.

To get around that, you can customize the master page on your site so that the page will hide the ribbon and navigation bars when some other (custom) query string parameter is provided.

For example, you could add the following code to your site's master page, before the closing `</head>` tag.

```
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
if(GetUrlKeyValue("dialog") == "1"){
    var ribbon = document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow");
    if(typeof(ribbon) != "undefined"){ ribbon.style.display = "none";}
    var nots = document.querySelectorAll(".s4-notdlg");
    for(var i = 0; i < nots.length; i++){nots[i].style.display="none";}
    document.getElementById("MSO_ContentTable").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}},"SP.JS");
</script>
```

After that you'd be able to append `?dialog=1` to a page's url to achieve an effect similar to `isDlg=1`, except that it should work on wiki pages.

Comment: It should work on any SharePoint page; I use it pretty regularly. Are there any other query string parameters in the URL that you're trying to link to? If so, you'll want to use `&isDlg=1` instead of `?isDlg=1`. Also, what version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: Well, the `&isDlg=1` will load a blank and not an error; that is an improvement.  Sharepoint 2010 enterprise.  No, there are no other query string parameters.

Comment: Ah.. I might know the answer. Is the page you're trying to display a wiki page, by any chance? `?isDlg=1` will work on web part pages (such as the kind you can create in the Pages library when you activate the publishing site features), but not on wiki pages, which throw a fit when they can't find the ribbon.

Comment: Yes, it is a wiki (I did say that in the question).  Thanks for answering, however.

Comment: I updated my answer with a trick you could pull in the master page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution that involves a Content Editor and jQuery.load(). You can "screen scrape" the section of the source page and stuff it into an HTML element of your choosing on the destination page. It would look something like this:

```
$("#myDiv").load("/SitePages/Blah.aspx .ms-WPBody");
```

In this example, "myDiv" is the ID of a div you'd place in your CEWP, and the argument passed into the load() function is the server-relative url of the source page,then a space followed by the CSS selector of the destination page content. Note that you must escape any spaces in the page url if there are any, because jQuery interprets the first space it finds as the delimiter between the url and the selector.

http://api.jquery.com/load/
(Check out the section titled "loading page fragments")

Comment: That's an idea; but I don't want to do this for every page.  I'd rather have a global solution that I could load using a query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting several content editors on the web-part page, and moving the wiki content from the pages in Site Pages to the wiki content of the content editor on the web-part page.  Not what I originally had in mind, but at least I don't have to do tricks to get what I want!

However, even though this is a solution, it isn't the best solution.